# codeigniter's pagination css not working

Tags: css, codeigniter, pagination

**NOTE** : I just realized that something is wrong with my CSS, the browser only view my old css (means that i cant edit my css). Whats wrong?

I tried to follow this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-7-pagination/) , but i dont do the exact same thing like the video.

I want to edit the appereance of my `pagination` links (using `codeigniter`). This is the controller code :

```
//pagination
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('/backend/umat/');
    //$config['base_url'] ='http://localhost/ci_gabdb/index.php/backend/umat/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->backend_m->count_umat();
    $config['per_page'] = 10; 
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Notice that i already use `full_tag_open` and `full_tag_close`. I also tried to manually insert the `<div>` tag in html, but none of them working.

This is my `css` code :

```
#pagination a {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #292929;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #e3e3e3;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 4px 7px;
}
```

I think the paginations css should working properly, but its not. Where is my mistake? Thanks :D

Comment: Is the rest of your CSS working properly? Open the page in Chrome, right click one of the links and choose inspect element. It's possible you have some other CSS that is overriding what you've put there. For example if you have CSS marked as important it would override anything else. from the looks of what you have above you're correct it should be working. For the record I never bother with the full tag thing at all. I just drop the pagination inside a div in the HTML with my class attached.

Comment: @RickCalder please see my edited question, i just realized that none of my new-edited css is working now (but the old one is working)

Comment: Are you doing this locally or on the server. Either way refresh the page a few times by hitting ctrl + F5 sounds like your browser is caching the CSS.

Comment: @RickCalder YES, you are right, i tried to close the tab, open it again, but its not working. I also click the url and press "Enter", its still not working. But when i just hit "F5", ITS WORING :D I dont know whats going on here, please answer the question (and with explanation, if its okay with you). Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a browser caching problem. There are a couple of solutions, hitting CTRL + F5 a few times in any browser will force a full refresh of the site. There are other ways to force CSS refreshes. One is to append a querystring to the CSS in your code the one I use in development is this:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/main.css?time=<?php echo filemtime('./assets/css/main.css');?>" />
```

What that does is append the end of the css with a query string and changes with the time, so every time I load the page my browser thinks it's a new version of the CSS and reloads it.

You can also tell your browser to reload the entire page on every visit, where this setting is differs in all the browsers but in Chrome it's

Settings > Advanced Settings > Change Proxy Settings > General Tab > Browser History Settings > Temporary Internet Files change the radio button to every time I load a web page.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I am using:

```
    // pagination code
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "/themes/all";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->auth_model->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 30;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] = round($choice);
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination pagination-large"><ul>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '«';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '»';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] =  '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["themes"] = $this->auth_model->fetch_themes_total($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    // pagination ends here
```

Comment: Which basically is what he has with a few extra tags, not really an answer to his question.

Comment: Thanks for your help :D I think the problem is not in my controller

Comment: @Rick ... Its just for him to compare and maybe try including the <ul> in the $config['full_tag_open'].